# Get package root and full module name from .py file for importing

Tags: python, import, module, package

I'm looking for a simple and fast way to find the root of the package and the full module name from a path to .py file.

I want the user to choose a .py and import it without breaking. Importing a module if it's part of the package will likely break. Thus I want to automatically append the directory wherein the root of the package resides to sys.path (if not already in there) and then import the module with its full module name.

I'm not running anywhere from the same directory or from that script, so I can't use `__file__` and that kind of thing. Also I don't have the module imported yet, so I can't (as far as I know) inspect the module object, because there is none.

This is a working version, yet I'm interested in finding easier/faster solutions.

```
def splitPathFull(path):
    folders=[]
    while 1:
        path,folder=os.path.split(path)

        if folder!="":
            folders.append(folder)
        else:
            if path!="":
                folders.append(path)

            break

    folders.reverse()
    return folders

def getPackageRootAndModuleNameFromFilePath(filePath):
    """
        It recursively looks up until it finds a folder without __init__.py and uses that as the root of the package
        the root of the package.
    """
    folder = os.path.dirname(filePath)
    if not os.path.exists( folder ):
        raise RuntimeError( "Location does not exist: {0}".format(folder) )

    if not filePath.endswith(".py"):
        return None

    moduleName = os.path.splitext( os.path.basename(filePath) )[0] # filename without extension

    #
    # If there's a __init__.py in the folder:
    #   Find the root module folder by recursively going up until there's no more __init__.py
    # Else:
    #   It's a standalone module/python script.
    #
    foundScriptRoot = False
    fullModuleName = None
    rootPackagePath = None
    if not os.path.exists( os.path.join(folder, "__init__.py" ) ):
        rootPackagePath = folder
        fullModuleName = moduleName
        foundScriptRoot = True
        # It's not in a Python package but a seperate ".py" script
        # Thus append it's directory name to sys path (if not in there) and import the .py as a module
    else:
        startFolder = folder

        moduleList = []
        if moduleName != "__init__":
            moduleList.append(moduleName)

        amountUp = 0
        while os.path.exists( folder ) and foundScriptRoot == False:

            moduleList.append ( os.path.basename(folder) )
            folder = os.path.dirname(folder)
            amountUp += 1

            if not os.path.exists( os.path.join(folder, "__init__.py" ) ):
                foundScriptRoot = True
                splitPath = splitPathFull(startFolder)
                rootPackagePath = os.path.join( *splitPath[:-amountUp] )
                moduleList.reverse()
                fullModuleName = ".".join(moduleList)

    if fullModuleName == None or rootPackagePath == None or foundScriptRoot == False:
        raise RuntimeError( "Couldn't resolve python package root python path and full module name for: {0}".format(filePath) )

    return [rootPackagePath, fullModuleName]

def importModuleFromFilepath(filePath, reloadModule=True):
    """
        Imports a module by it's filePath.
        It adds the root folder to sys.path if it's not already in there.
        Then it imports the module with the full package/module name and returns the imported module as object.
    """

    rootPythonPath, fullModuleName = getPackageRootAndModuleNameFromFilePath(filePath)

    # Append rootPythonPath to sys.path if not in sys.path
    if rootPythonPath not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(rootPythonPath)

    # Import full (module.module.package) name
    mod = __import__( fullModuleName, {}, {}, [fullModuleName] )
    if reloadModule:
        reload(mod)

    return mod
```

Comment: Just a question; why? What is the end goal? Is this just an excersize?

Comment: I'm trying to create an API that allows for designing plugins / additional classes outside of the program's python package. This would be used for creating new classes that would define new object types. I want the user to say 'include this file/folder in your object type inventory'. Yet this file/folder could be part of another project/package which when importing it on its own could break some of the code. (right?) I need to import the file to get the class, but also check if it is a valid new class. Eventually leading to something like. import package; package.addPluginPath("filepath")

Comment: @RoyNieterau You should only need to `try: except:` the loading of the module to deal with the case of an invalid import. I'm not sure any plugin architecture is going to be 100% safe... there's too many introspection tools in Python that will allow any plugins to mess with the running interpreter.

Comment: You might like to read PEP 420, *Namespace packages*, as implemented in Python 3.3.  That will either do what you want (I'm not clear on that), or at least break your assumptions about `__init__.py`.

Comment: @cdarke. The .pyp files would still be imported with Python's 'import' function as that functionality will be extended. At first sight importing the file from the root of the package will still work, and the actual import will use its .pyp functionality and the ideas presented in PEP420 without breaking the main concept that anything with __init__.py is a package (which in itself will import modules at different locations, but that is done whenever the first package gets imported.) The main difference is that .pyp files can be imported on their own and redirect the import to different paths.

Comment: Therefore the basis I'm looking for should still work in those cases, right? (Although the script above will only check .py files, but should allow the user to select a .pyp file as 'plugin file' as well.) I looked for PEP420 but read through a different document instead, DOH! I just went through PEP420 quickly looking over the basic details, yet still it seems that the main import statement will do all the different path searching.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible due to [namespace packages](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification) - there is simply no way to decide whether the correct package for `baz.py` is `foo.bar` or just `bar` with the following file structure:

```
foo/
    bar/
        __init__.py
        baz.py
```

Comment: How would this work with the namespace packages? What path should be in sys.path and what would be the module to import. How would you define that foo.bar would be the correct path for this? Would that be coded within 'baz.py'? I've been reading through PEP420 but was unable to see how this works. Also, would this only be a problem with python 3.2+?

Comment: PEP420 is fairly simple: It starts to import regular packages and modules and captures all *candidates* for namespace packages along the way. If it can't find anything, it makes a namespace package out of the list of candidates. And yes, if you're targeting Python<3.3, you don't need to worry about that.